# Count in QUERY to include counts for all unique items (dates)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

```
=query(A:B,"Select A, Count(B) where A is not null and B='A' group by A,1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"Data", "Count Amount"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({UNIQUE(A3:A), 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A3:A), 
 QUERY(A:B, "select A,count(B) 
             where A is not null 
               and B='A' 
             group by A 
             label count(B)''", 0), 2, 0), 0)},
 "where Col1 is not null"))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I have another question.
If I want just Column 'E' how I can do? (no need Data of date)

thank you so much

Comment: @PeaceZ https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask