# How to have a query wrapped in an arrayformula auto-populate many rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I have a `query` that queries over a set of rows. I want to run this `query`, itself, for each row in another set of rows. The one value that changes in the `query` for each row is something in the `where` clause. I am trying to wrap the `query` in an `arrayformula` so that I only have to put the formula in the top cell and it will auto-populate, but it will not 'auto-populate'. How do I do this?

Example is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oC2_d4oHr98nFmZb2MqZvdgPSCd955JdztJHRLYXQzI/edit#gid=0).

[image: example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count in QUERY to include counts for all unique items (dates)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/128974/count-in-query-to-include-counts-for-all-unique-items-dates)

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Place this formula in the top cell (i.e., header cell) of any otherwise empty column:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header";IF(B2:B="",,COUNTIF(A2:A,B2:B))})`

`QUERY` is not necessary, as you can see.

You can change the "Header" text to whatever you like.

Another option would be to place the following formula in the top left cell of any *two* otherwise empty columns:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A2:A},"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Categories', COUNT(Col1) 'Header 2'"))`

This formula would produce the "Categories" list and the count of each unique category (i.e., a two-column array).